# A word to refer to a text fragment that is not transcribed (or probably transcribed incorrectly) from spoken material?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let’s say I want to decipher (transcribe) some spoken material (voice) to text, but after doing this, I doubt if some parts have been transcribed correctly. What is appropriate word to describe such parts?
Another situation: when someone says something, but you cannot decipher some part to convert it to a written text. How to refer to such parts? “Gaps”? “Blanks”?

Comment: The former is surely just *mistranscribed*?

Comment: I'd use question marks. As in: _"...cutter (could've?) shaped heartaches..."_

Comment: @Okoning - thank you, but... there is a very important nuance! "Mistranscribed" means transcribed incorrectly, right? But what if this fragment is correct??? I don't know! I said "I doubt if some parts have been transcribed correctly"! Will this word be appropriate in this case?

Comment: @TusharRaj: I'm asking for a word to **refer to (describe)** such parts, not how to mark them.

Comment: Well, maybe it is better just to use two words "**probably** mistranscribed", I was just wondering if there is a simpler construction to use in such situation...

Comment: A *dubious* transcription, I suppose.

Comment: @Okoning - thank you again, this is interesting! So, how exactly should it be used to refer to a fragment? "Parts/fragments of _(a? the? which article, if needed?)_ dubious transcription"?

Comment: *"This part of the transcription is dubious; I cannot for sure make out what was said."*

Comment: Which version should I present to the general public? 1. "Dubious parts are marked by red wavy underline" 2. "Parts of dubious transcription are marked by red wavy underline" 3. "Possibly mistranscribed parts are marked by red wavy underline".

Comment: "Some parts of the transcription are dubious because the speech at those points was indecipherable. I have underlined such parts in red."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when someone says something, but you cannot decipher some part to
>   convert it to a written text. How to refer to such parts? “Gaps”?
>   “Blanks”?

You could call the gaps in the transcription *lacunae*.

**The *lacunae* in the transcript represent places where the speech was
either inaudible or unintelligible.**

See *lacuna*.

If you're not leaving blanks but making guesses when you cannot make out clearly what is being said, then those places could be called "conjectural transcriptions".

Comment: To make this answer complete you should define lacuna and cite the source of your definition.

Comment: For my comment above, which version (of the three) would you recommend?

Comment: @okoning. One could look it up in any dictionary.  I've added the singular.

Comment: @lyrically wicked:  if you're making guesses when you cannot hear the speech, or where you cannot really make out what is said, then there you don't have "gaps" in your transcript. You could refer to those places in the transcript as "conjectural transcriptions". BTW, not all media support wavy red underlining, so that typographical solution isn't amenable to being quoted elsewhere.  You might want to consider {curly braces} or *{curly braces and italics}* instead.  #3 is the best, IMO. But I'd say "conjectural transcriptions".

Comment: @TimRomano - please, include "conjectural transcriptions" in the answer.

Comment: @lyrically wicked: done.

Comment: @TimRomano: I know that one could look it up in any dictionary. The point is that by defining it yourself you prevent the reader from having to do so. This make your answer a more useful submission by itself.

Comment: @Okoning: My goal is to *encourage* people to consult a dictionary or ideally several dictionaries, so I demur to the request.